# Vanity urls for files in Vue 2.1

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Reading through the Vue Router [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html) this seems like it should be pretty simply, but I can't get it to work.

First I tried to use the file in S3

```
{
  path: '/rules',
  redirect: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/itsclarke/vue-project/pdfs/rules.pdf'
}
```

This resulted in the redirect being appended to `localhost:8080/#`, so I got `localhost:8080/#/https://s3.amazonaws.com/...`

Also tried using the same approach with the `static` folder:

```
{
  path: '/rules',
  redirect: '../../static/rules.pdf'
}
```

This kept the path relative, but inestead of showing the pdf, it took me to `localhost:8080/#/static/rules.pdf` which isn't the path. `localhost:8080/static/rules.pdf` is what I need. This needs to use `hash` mode as well.

Using alias mode isn't much help either because I don't have components for these files. I know these redirects can be down on the server level, but I want to do it within Vue Router.

Comment: Just to clarify ... you want a client-side route that redirects the user to a server side resource?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with vue-router ... a redirect should return another client side route, not a server-side url. I think your best bet would be to use a `beforeEnter` guard on your `/rules` route to redirect (using `window.location`) to the url. Alternatively, you could have your `/rules` route return a component that displays the pdf in an iframe.

Comment: @Peter your beforeEnter suggestion actually worked, thanks. If you submit it as an answer, I'll give you some free internet points.

Comment: Cool - glad this worked for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible out of the box with vue-router - it expects the redirect value to be another client-side route, not a server-side url. I think your best bet would be to use a `beforeEnter` guard on your `/rules` route to redirect (using `window.location`) to the url. Alternatively, you could have your `/rules` route return a component that displays the pdf in an iframe.